# Update a field model_type='App\Models\User' is not getting actual result in php mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute this query "UPDATE model_has_roles SET model_type='App\Models\User'" But I'm getting the update result is 'AppModelsUser' but I need the result  'App\Models\User'.

Can anyone help me? how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem in this way -
UPDATE model_has_roles SET model_type='App\\Models\\User'